# How to echo from one php file into another?

Tags: php, arrays, templates, include

I have a phpfile "read.php" which reads the database and does an echo

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "dbpass";
$db_name = "dbname";


$conID = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass ) or die( "Die Datenbank konnte       nicht erreicht werden!" );
 if ($conID)
{
mysql_select_db( $db_name, $conID );
}

$sql = "SELECT `version` FROM `versionierung`";

$abfrageergebnis = mysql_query( $sql, $conID );

while ($datensatz = mysql_fetch_array( $abfrageergebnis ))

{    
echo "<td>" .htmlspecialchars( $datensatz['version'] ). "</td>";
}


?>
```

To include the output in my template I first have to get this echo into another php files array. How can I include this echo into my other.php

```
$tplMainPage = array(
                     'read'     =>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is a good practice, but you can use php output buffering.

```
ob_start();
while ($datensatz = mysql_fetch_array( $abfrageergebnis ))

{    
 echo "<td>" .htmlspecialchars( $datensatz['version'] ). "</td>";
}
$content = ob_get_clean();
require 'other.php';
```

Now your echo contents are in the $content variable.

Comment: I don't know the structure of the entire script, but i think you can simply include your file after the $content variable.